# Is there a way to generate an image based on the user's name like iOS7 Favourites using a web language?

Tags: javascript, php, image, laravel, gd

[image: iOS7 Favourites]

In this screenshot of iOS7 Favourites, when a photo doesn't exist for a particular user, a placeholder image is displayed using the initials of said contact.

Is there a way to do this for the web? A service like [lorempixel](http://lorempixel.com)? Or can this be done in a web language using an image library?

I would like the images to either be square or a circle with the user's initials inside.

I am creating a project in Laravel and I know that it has some image manipulation facilities built in and PHP has a GD library.

Answer (score 3):

Yes.You can generate an image from string using True Type fonts.

Example borrowed from: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagettftext.php

```
<?php
// Set the content-type
header('Content-Type: image/png');

// Create the image
$im = imagecreatetruecolor(400, 30);

// Create some colors
$white = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);
$grey = imagecolorallocate($im, 128, 128, 128);
$black = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0);
imagefilledrectangle($im, 0, 0, 399, 29, $white);

// The text to draw
$text = 'Testing...';
// Replace path by your own font path
$font = 'arial.ttf';

// Add some shadow to the text
imagettftext($im, 20, 0, 11, 21, $grey, $font, $text);

// Add the text
imagettftext($im, 20, 0, 10, 20, $black, $font, $text);

// Using imagepng() results in clearer text compared with imagejpeg()
imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
?>
```

The result will be:

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Is there a way to generate these images and save them to an appropriate file so that I can reference them later. I want one for each letter A-Z and for each two letter combo AA-ZZ?

Comment: @Mike, yes you can, in that code just remove "header('Content-Type: image/png');" and edit imagepng funtion, add imagepng($im, "filename.png");

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want o reinvent the wheel, now we have some libraries to do this task.

[Avatar](https://github.com/MatthewCallis/avatar): is a JavaScript library for showing Gravatars or generating user avatars. This one provides a plenty of options to do the task in the **front end**.

```
import Avatar from 'avatar-initials';

const avatar = new Avatar(document.getElementById('avatar'), {
  useGravatar: true, // Allow Gravatars or not.
  fallbackImage: '', // URL or Data URI used when no initials are provided and not using Gravatars.
  size: 80,          // Size in pixels, fallback for hidden images and Gravatar

  // Initial Avatars Specific
  initials: '',          // Initials to be used.
  initial_fg: '#888888', // Text Color
  initial_bg: '#f4f6f7', // Background Color
  initial_size: null,    // Text Size in pixels
  initial_weight: 100,   // Font weight (numeric value for light, bold, etc.)
  initial_font_family: "'Lato', 'Lato-Regular', 'Helvetica Neue'",

  // Gravatar Specific
  hash: null,                   // Precalculated MD5 string of an email address
  email: null,                  // Email used for the Gravatar
  fallback: 'mm',               // Fallback Type
  rating: 'x',                  // Gravatar Rating
  forcedefault: false,          // Force Gravatar Defaults
  allowGravatarFallback: false, // Use Gravatars fallback, not fallbackImage

  // GitHub Specific
  github_id: null,  // GitHub User ID.

  // Avatars.io Specific
  use_avatars_io: false, // Enable Avatars.io Support
  avatars_io: {
    user_id: null,       // Avatars.io User ID
    identifier: null,    // Avatars.io Avatar Identifier
    twitter: null,       // Twitter ID or Username
    facebook: null,      // Facebook ID or Username
    instagram: null,     // Instagram ID or Username
    size: 'medium',      // Size: small, medium, large
  },

  setSourceCallback: null, // Callback called when image source is set (useful to cache avatar sources provided by third parties such as Gravatar)
});
```

[No Avatar](https://github.com/thatisuday/npm-no-avatar): Node.js Module and Express middleware to generate avatar image with initials in the **back end**. What you have to do is to build an object with options to choose text, colors and size of the image.

```
const { save } =  require('no-avatar');
const savePath = __dirname + '/avatar.png';
const options = {
    width: 150,
    height: 150,
    text: userInitials,
    bgColor: 000000,
    fontColor: FFFFFF,
    fontSize: 60
};

save(savePath, options, function(err){
    if(err) return console.log(err);
            return console.log('avatar.png saved at path ' + savePath);
});
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/21378023)

Comment: I edited my answer with more details. However, it depends on the libraries from the links to work.